# Computing the sum of the numbers with a define statement-python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
data = [92.5, 87.7, 74.8, 93., 91.7, 90.0, 90.3, 92.5, 100.0, 
  100.0, 35.7, 37.4, 21.0]

def data_sum(data):
    total=0.0
    for element in data:
        total+=element
    return total
```

My task is to find the sum of the list above and that is what I came up with so far, however when I go to run the file it returns empty. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're not calling the function in your script. Add `data_sum(data)` after the function definition.

Comment: Do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You are not making any call to this function, that is why your code is not executing. You can call your function as:

```
data_sum(data)
```

However, there is `sum()` function in Python that returns the sum of the `list` if the list is of numeric type. Ideal way to get the sum of numeric list is by using [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). Hence your code should be:

```
sum(data)
```

where `data` is the `list` as is mentioned in the question.

Comment: What's the point of wrapping the sum function in another function? You can equivalently could use function objects `data_sum = sum`

Comment: @cricket_007: User has specifically mentioned that he needs to create a new function "Computing the sum of the numbers with a *define statement*". But I agree with you, it truly doesn't  makes any sense. :/

Comment: By the way I have updated the answer. Even I felt that I was stupid in mentioning it over there

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function like the below example:

```
data = [92.5, 87.7, 74.8, 93., 91.7, 90.0, 90.3, 92.5, 100.0,
        100.0, 35.7, 37.4, 21.0]


def data_sum(data):
    total = 0.0
    for element in data:
        total += element
    return total

print data_sum(data)
```

Another possible ways to sum values from a list are using the builtin-functions  [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) or [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), like this:

```
print sum(data)
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, data)
```